# VS Code failing to create or load polyglot notebooks following .NET SDK reinstall

Tags: visual-studio-code, .net-core, polyglot-notebooks

My company's brilliant IT department has an unfortunate habit of uninstalling .NET SDK versions that they perceive to be out of date. Recently they uninstalled .NET SDK 6.  I have successfully got them to reinstall it, but since then I observe the following behaviour from VS Code:

- When I open an existing, known-good .dib file the notebook doesn't open and I see the horizontal "progress bar" at the top of the window throbbing forever.
- When I create a new notebook nothing visibly happens at all.

Any idea what log files I can look at the try and fault find this?  Or what I can change or install?

Here's my dotnet --info

```
dotnet --info
.NET SDK:
 Version:   7.0.306
 Commit:    f500069cb7

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.19045
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.306\

Host:
  Version:      7.0.11
  Architecture: x64
  Commit:       ecb34f85ec

.NET SDKs installed:
  6.0.414 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  7.0.306 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.22 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]        
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.22 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 7.0.10 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 7.0.11 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.22 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 7.0.11 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]

Other architectures found:
  x86   [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet]
    registered at [HKLM\SOFTWARE\dotnet\Setup\InstalledVersions\x86\InstallLocation]

Environment variables:
  Not set

global.json file:
  Not found

Learn more:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet/info

Download .NET:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet/download
```

Things I have tried:

- rebooting
- uninstalling and reinstalling the Polyglot Notebooks extension
- installing the pre-release version of the Polyglot Notebooks extension

Edit:

For what it's worth, here are the extension logs for when I try to create new blank notebook.

```
2023-09-15 10:51:30.781 [info] ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension ms-toolsai.jupyter, startup: false, activationEvent: 'onCommand:polyglot-notebook.newNotebook', root cause: ms-dotnettools.dotnet-interactive-vscode
2023-09-15 10:51:31.005 [info] ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension ms-python.python, startup: false, activationEvent: 'api', root cause: ms-toolsai.jupyter
2023-09-15 10:51:31.033 [info] ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension ms-toolsai.jupyter-renderers, startup: false, activationEvent: 'api', root cause: ms-toolsai.jupyter
2023-09-15 10:51:31.034 [info] ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension ms-dotnettools.dotnet-interactive-vscode, startup: false, activationEvent: 'onCommand:polyglot-notebook.newNotebook'
2023-09-15 10:51:31.211 [info] ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension ms-python.vscode-pylance, startup: false, activationEvent: 'api', root cause: ms-python.python
```

Edit 2: Also raised as an issue here: https://github.com/dotnet/interactive/issues/3178

Answer (score 1):

IT installed the latest .NET 7 SDK (so now I have 3) and that fixed it:

.NET SDKs installed:
6.0.414 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
7.0.306 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
7.0.401 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]